# How Many Times Can You Tweet the Same Tweet

Tags: networking, twitter, social-networking

How Many Times Can You Tweet the Same Tweet

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using the Twitter user interface, not programming within the scope defined in the [help].

Comment: @Quantas 94 Heavy where would I go to ask a question about Twitter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter prevents you from tweeting the same tweet twice in a row. You can tweet something else in-between two tweets of the same content.

If you do need to tweet the same information continuously, add a time-stamp.

Comment: you can tweet the same tweet, there just has to be another tweet in between.

Comment: You're correct @Pinna_be, I've corrected it.